# Require Mongodb without download?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to add access to a mongodb database inside a userscript for an online browser game that uses node.js and socket.io. The userscript would just be a js program that a user would install through tampermonkey.

Since the game doesn't use mongodb, is there a way I can require it through an online CDN like how you can include jQuery through google's? I probably have a complete misunderstanding of how javascript modules work so excuse me for the beginner question.

Comment: So you want to expose your entire database to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *really* need mongoDB on the client side? Surely there's a better way... Not to mention, there are built-in mini-databases client side you have access to, mind you (like indexedDB, Web SQL, or just json in localStorage). Also, check out mini Mongo.